# Cypress : Getting an element from a table using another element as reference

Tags: javascript, testing, html-table, cypress, tr

ok, so here is the situation. I have a webpage where I add elements to a table, and when I add that element , the webpage automatically assign a number for it.

My question is: How can I get that number ? Because its automatically generated, so I have no way of knowing which number its going to be. The table is something like that:

Name Number 
Orange 35
Apple  452
Lemon  77

And the code :

```
<tr data-id="77">
                    <td class="col col-md-5 text-left">
                        Lemon
                    </td>
                    <td class="col col-md-5 text-left">
                        77
                    </td>
</tr>
```

as you can see, the number 77 does not have a unique identifier and when I created Lemon, I have no way of knowing what that number would be.

My first idea was to get the element on the left, which is Lemon, because I know its name (its me who gives its name, using .type() and then try and getting the element to the right of Lemon, which will be a number that I have no idea what number its going to be.

Is that possible? Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

```
cy.contains('td.col', 'lemon').siblings('td.col').invoke('text').as('lemonNumber');
// or
cy.contains('td.col', 'lemon').parent('tr').invoke('data', 'id').as('lemonNumber');
// or for each row
cy.get('tr').each((row, index) => {
  cy.wrap(row).contains('td', /\w+/).invoke('text').as('rowName' + index);
  cy.wrap(row).contains('td', /\d+/).invoke('text').as('rowNumber' + index);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what the exact number content is or a distinguishing feature of the containing element, you will need one of relative-selecting commands,

**[Siblings](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/siblings.html)**

```
cy.contains('td', 'Lemon')
  .siblings().eq(0)
  .invoke('text')
  .then(lemonText => {
    const lemonNumber = +lemonText.trim();
    // do something with lemonNumber
})
```

**[Next](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next.html)**

```
cy.contains('td', 'Lemon')
  .next('td')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(lemonText => {
    const lemonNumber = +lemonText.trim();
    // do something with lemonNumber
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
cy.get('[data-id="77"] td:nth-child(2)').should('have.text', '77')
```

Comment: This would not work, because I dont know what the number would be. It generates a random number.